# HashBuiltin - Cairo

Tags: starknet, cairo-lang

I am having this  `contract.cairo:3:59: Unknown identifier 'HashBuiltin'`
after doing :

> starknet-compile contract.cairo 
> --output contract_compiled.json 
> --abi contract_abi.json

code :

```
@external
func increase_balance{syscall_ptr : felt*, pedersen_ptr : HashBuiltin*, range_check_ptr}(
        amount : felt):
    let (res) = balance.read()
    balance.write(res + amount)
    return ()
end

# Returns the current balance.
@view
func get_balance{syscall_ptr : felt*, pedersen_ptr : HashBuiltin*, range_check_ptr}() -> (
        res : felt):
    let (res) = balance.read()
    return (res=res)
end
```

Any explanation ?

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to add

```
from starkware.cairo.common.cairo_builtins import HashBuiltin
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add this line to import it from Cairo libraries.

```
from starkware.cairo.common.cairo_builtins import HashBuiltin
```

That should do the trick.